How do Angular's computed() signals work internally?
I don't understand how computed() works internally. How does Angular knows when to update it ? The docs don't mention it.
From the docs :

The doubleCount signal depends on the count signal. Whenever count
updates, Angular knows that doubleCount needs to update as well.
doubleCount's derivation function does not run to calculate its value
until the first time you read doubleCount. The calculated value is
then cached, and if you read doubleCount again, it will return the
cached value without recalculating. If you then change count, Angular
knows that doubleCount's cached value is no longer valid, and the next
time you read doubleCount its new value will be calculated.

They say that "Angular knows" two times but never explain how Angular knows this.
import { Component, computed, input } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentChartData } from '../../../../models/component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrl: './chart.component.scss',
})
export class ChartComponent {
  chartData = input.required<ComponentChartData>();
  datasets = computed(() => this.chartData().datasets);
}


This is described very well in the docs: https://angular.dev/guide/signals#computed-signals

I’m voting to close this question because it can be answered by reading the official documentation.

@JSONDerulo according to your logic 99% of SO questions should be closed, especially old ones

Furthermore, in no way the angular docs addresses the OP question. OP didn't ask how computed works in general, but how it works internally. That's actually complex and may deserve a thorough answer

"The doubleCount signal depends on the count signal. Whenever count updates, Angular knows that doubleCount needs to update as well. doubleCount's derivation function does not run to calculate its value until the first time you read doubleCount. The calculated value is then cached, and if you read doubleCount again, it will return the cached value without recalculating. If you then change count, Angular knows that doubleCount's cached value is no longer valid, and the next time you read doubleCount its new value will be calculated." I think that perfectly answers the question.

This is describing how it works. Would you be able to code it?

Where does the author ask how to code this??

Also I disagree to the statement that "99% of SO questions are like this one". The majority of questions are related to specific programming problems, this question asks for an explanation how something works, in my experience those are in the minority. It's also fine to ask such questions, if there are no reputable sources which answer the question (at the time). It is expected for an author of a question to do some research and at least check the official docs. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

So the doubleCount signal "depends" on the count signal, indeed. Can you tell me how so ? How does Angular knows this ? Are they introspecting the computed function's body ? What tells angular that this signal needs an update ? I do not understand what isn't clear in my question, reading it again I don't see what I need to edit. Or maybe you read it too fast ? How does the docs (that I read before asking) answers this question ? The part you copy/pasted does not answer this at all.

Take a look to this link It's a bit hard but ...

Great article Eliseo, thank you ! This answers my question. Ultimatly that's all that matters to me. If SO doesn't need this post or it's answer in another debate that I do not care about.

The question "How does Angular knows when to update it" is vague, apparently it can be interpreted in different ways. My interpretation was that you want to understand the concept. If you understand the general concept but want to know how it's implemented internally, you should mention this in your question.

This question might be answered on different levels of complexity. Without digging into source code the 'simple' answer is that Angular uses Dynamic Dependency tracking if you want to dig into the source code I'd recommend to start with producerUpdateValueVersion. From other sources you might take a look at this blog post
